# kendo ui for jquery. Where are child columns stored in setOptions

Tags: jquery, for-loop, user-interface, kendo-ui

I cannot work out how to set the CHILD grid column widths and positions.
I can set all the master grid column widths and positions.

When calling grid.getOptions(), I can only see a reference to the MASTER grid column properties.

I can set all the master grid column widths and positions with this function:

```
function setColumFormat(){
    var grid = $("#kdClaimStatus").data("kendoGrid");  
    var options = localStorage["grid-column-options"];  
    if (options) {  
        var parsedOptions = JSON.parse(options);  
        var columns = parsedOptions.columns;
        grid.setOptions({ columns: columns });  
    }  
}
```

But I cannot work out how to set the CHILD grid column widths and positions.
I have searched Telerik documentation and cannot find any solution.